# How to use substantial responsibilities outside of the job description (but still related) to justify a raise?

Tags: software-industry, salary, software-development

I'm currently a junior (back-end) software developer in the Netherlands.
My job description only requires me to work on the back-end in one programming language.

In practice I am required to work in **two** different languages and am carrying out work on the front-end as well.

Additionally I am working on server administration, hosting, dealing direct with the customer and recently have been dealing with the incoming GDPR legislation.

How can I use these additional responsibilities/tasks to ask for a raise?

And what is the best way to communicate this request to management?

Comment: You can always ask. Advice is typically out of scope here.

Comment: The only way to be sure that you get what you ask for is to ask for nothing.

Comment: @paparazzo this entire site is about giving advice. I know what you're getting at, but "advice" probably isn't the word to use. "We can't tell you what to do" is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience job descriptions in IT/development are pretty much meaningless, very few roles condense easily into a few lines and there will *always* be ancillary tasks that fall outside of it.

However these additional responsibilities you describe sound, for the most part, like a reasonably common career development trajectory for a junior developer. And if they are taking up a non-trivial amount of your time - and most importantly if you are doing them ***well*** then they are a good basis to ask for a salary increase.

The best way to do this is to arrange a 1-1 meeting with your manager (or use your next performance review if it's soon enough for you) and make your case about how these additional tasks you are carrying out are *bringing value to the company* over and above your standard duties. Go armed with specific examples of ones that went well and of skills you have acquired.

Attitude is key here, going in with

> I'm doing all this stuff that isn't in my job description, it's not fair. You need to pay me more

isn't likely to go down well. Whereas:

> I really feel like I've grown during my time here. I've learnt *language x* and used it to implement front end widgets *a, b & c* and I really feel that I'm bringing much more value to the company as a result

is *much* more positive and get's your manager thinking along the right lines i.e. about what they are getting for their money.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing enough information. You are involved in a second programming language but how complex are the tasks you are doing? Are you doing overtime due to workload?
Assessing if what you are doing is impressive enough to deserve a raise is hard.
However the most usual path for a raise is promotion. You are a junior programmer as you mentioned so you could present a case if you can prove that what you do requires skill above a junior.
Usually a promotion means a raise.  It is much easier to get a promotion than just ask for a raise usually but experiences vary